# PostSharp Starter Edition - How to add license to a project

Tags: .net, postsharp

I have downloaded and installed the starter edition of postsharp and have entered my license key for postsharp on my machine using PostSharp 2.0 User options.  When I check the project in and it runs my  ci environment (hudson) the build fails.  How can I setup postsharp so that it will build correctly on the build server and also build on another developers pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot more googling I found [this](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/Build-Servers-and-Deploying-Licenses-in-Source-Control.aspx) blog post.
It appears from what is in this post that this can't be done with the starter edition of postsharp.